# Selecting different rows from different GroupBy groups

Tags: python, pandas

As opposed to [GroupBy.nth](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html), which selects the same index for each group, I would like to take specific indices from each group. For example, if my GroupBy object consisted of four groups and I would like the 1st, 5th, 10th, and 15th from each respectively, then I would like to be able to pass `x = [0, 4, 9, 14]` and get those rows.

Comment: Something like: `df.groupby(...).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[indices])`

Comment: actually that doesn't seem to work. it applies each index to each group so you get multiple rows from each group.

Comment: Okay, great. Because that wasn't clear from your question. "I would like to take specific indices from each group" implies you wanted the same indices from each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of a strange thing to want; is there a reason?

In any case, to do what you want, try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1], ['a', 2], 
                   ['b', 3], ['b', 4], ['b', 5], 
                   ['c', 6], ['c', 7]], 
                  columns=['group', 'value'])

def index_getter(which):
    def get(series):
        return series.iloc[which[series.name]]
    return get

which = {'a': 0, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}

df.groupby('group')['value'].apply(index_getter(which))
```

Which results in:

```
group
a    1
b    5
c    7
```

Comment: Thank you! Had to add a little code as `which = dict(zip(group_keys, x))`, but this did the trick. Thanks!